# Macro for concatenating array

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am having some array of value as below.

```
array(0) = "1"
array(1) = "2"
array(3) = "3"
.
.
.
array(n) = "n"
```

there are N number of array I have to append to string as

```
String = combined(array(0),array(1),.....,array(n))
```

can someone please advise.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to concatenate the whole array, use

```
myString = Join(array,"")
```

The second argument is the delimeter (default is `" "`, not `""`)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your N = 100 (for this example), see code below.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ex_Array()          As Variant
Dim i                   As Integer
Dim ans_str             As String

Sub concen()

ReDim ex_Array(0 To 100)    
ex_Array(0) = "1"
ex_Array(1) = "2"
ex_Array(3) = "3"

For i = 0 To UBound(ex_Array)
    ans_str = ans_str & ex_Array(i)    
Next i    
MsgBox ans_str

End Sub
```

Comment: it's making ans_str = 1 2 3 .. n .. but I actually needed as ans_str = conc(1,2,3,...n)

Comment: @user1954762 what do you want the answer to be ?